# Unity. Управление персонажем и анимации

Tags: unity3d

Уважаемые друзья. Решил я тут сделать небольшую игрушку, хотел как можно проще, а получилось как обычно. И застрял я в самом начале: В общем, есть некий скрипт, даже два. Один - на камеру, второй - на персонажа. Интересует именно по персонажу. В общем, игра с видом сверху, где персонаж крутится за курсором мыши. Но ходит он на WASD по глобальным координатам т.е. как бы не был повернут персонаж - W - это всегда на север и т.д. Теперь вопросы:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы кручение персонажа не затрагивало тогда, когда курсор находится рядом с персонажем (чтоб он не крутился на месте)
2. Как сделать, чтоб персонаж не крутился постоянно (у меня он крутит головой за курсором мыши - на курсоре висит пустой объект, а башка глав. героя смотрит на этот пустой объект через Animation Rigging (аддон)), так вот, если, к примеру, поворот менее 5 градусов, то чтоб персонаж и не крутился.
3. Почему у меня через несколько циклов анимации персонаж смещается и становится уже не в центре?
4. Как лучше сорганизовать управление? Т.к. анимаций слишком дофига, получается
5. Как сорганизовать смену анимаций с учетом моего управления? Или может есть какой-то аналог управления, также подобно шутеру? Потому что я так понимаю, что нужно вычислить угол между самим персонажем и курсором, затем этот угол брать и учитывать поворот модельки персонажа. И тогда применять анимацию, к примеру, если курсор справа, а персонаж идет на север (персонаж смотрит вправо, тело повренуто вправо, а я жму W и бегу вперед), то применять анимацию StrafeLeft (типа переступать влево), если при таком же положении мышки жму D (мышка от персонажа справа) - то он идет в сторону мышки и значит проигрывается анимация бега вперед, а если я нажму S+D и оставлю курсор в том же положении - тогда анимация поменяется наполовину (со смешиваниями анимаций немного знаком).

Может есть какой-то более простой способ управления? Я хотел сделать шутер с элементами РПГ и выживалки с видом как в Кримсонлэнд или алиен шутер, но для второй игры (уровень у меня полного нуба), видимо - тяжеловато.

Так же я в нижнем апдейте из аниматора беру анимации в зависимости от скорости движения персонажа. Там всё просто было бы, если бы игрок всегда смотрел бы только на север. Типа Если V больше нуля, тогда strafelеft, а если H больше нуля - тогда анимация runningforward и т.д.. А так у меня я хз как делать.

Один из вариантов такой, что можно сделать вид от третьего лица, тогда перед персонажа всегда будет туда, куда смотрит камера. Но это тогда хрень получится, если делать с "высоким" видом - голова у игрока закружится. При этом я бы хотел оставить свободный курсор.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header("Скорость:")]
    public float speed = 1.5f;
    public float acceleration = 100f;
        
    [Header("Поворот:")]
    public Transform bodyTransform; 
    public float smooth = 3;
    public bool useSmooth;

    [Header("Скрипт контроля камеры")]
    public Transform cameraParent;

    private Vector3 direction;
    private Rigidbody body;
    public Animator _anim;

    void Awake()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        body.freezeRotation = true;
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        body.AddForce(direction.normalized * acceleration * body.mass * speed);
        
        if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.x) > speed)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector3(Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.x) * speed, body.velocity.y, body.velocity.z);
        }
        if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.z) > speed)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector3(body.velocity.x, body.velocity.y, Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.z) * speed);
        }

        Rotation();
    }


    void Rotation() 
    {
        Vector3 lookPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.y)) - body.position;
        lookPos.y = 0; 

        if(useSmooth)
        {
            Quaternion playerRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
            bodyTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(bodyTransform.rotation, playerRotation, smooth * Time.fixedDeltaTime); 
        }
        else
        {
            bodyTransform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
        }

    }

    void Update()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        direction = new Vector3(h, 0, v);
        direction = cameraParent.TransformDirection(direction);
        direction = new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не знаю, чем закончиться вопрос, но хотел бы поиграть в это (старый поклонник crimsonland)

Comment: Ну здесь больше будет как из стареньких РПГшек с сюжетом, да с левелонабиванием, лол. Просто управление хотел сделать как в кримсонлэнде, но чую, что надо будет делать так, чтобы персонаж бежал туда, где курсор т.е. направление к курсору - это всегда вперед. Так может кто подскажет по управлению, либо вообще даст гайд на хороший видеоурок по подобному управлению. Потому что я нихрена не нашёл.

Comment: не знаю, поможет ли тебе это, но раздел с персонажем и уровнями вроде бы внятный. https://habr.com/ru/articles/278947/

Comment: Мне бы сейчас понять, как просто сделать, чтобы перед для персонажа был там, где курсор :) И задача сразу упростится.

Comment: Я задумался. Попробуй сделать ориентирование по пикселю. Условно верх это всегда движение по коду х, у. Т.е. при разрешении 1280х720 верх всегда будет очка х = 640, у = 0(или1). Аналогично для всех сторон. Такой вариант определения сторон подойдёт? Соответственно определять координаты надо внутри окна.

Comment: Нет, не пойдёт, потому что у меня камера плавает за игроком и не всегда игрок находится по центру экрана :) Буду переделывать управление, попробую сделать с root motion

Comment: В самом конце поменял: direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.y)) - body.position; , теперь у персонажа перед там, где курсор, вот только он не обращает внимания на кнопки, а как баран прет к курсору, без остановки.